# GTK# File Chooser Non Native Look on OSX

Tags: c#, macos, mono, gtk, gtk#

I have C# App using the Mono Framework and GTK UI running on Mac.I have problems regarding the look and feel of the Filechooser dialog.As per gtk https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooserDialog.html I should get these icons

[image]

But what i get is this one without proper icons in the left hand panel or icons of the drives.For drives there a folder named Volumes and the user needs to open it manually.I think that is not a native Mac user expects.I have posted 2 screenshots obtained from the web.

[image]

I have this GTK Version(2.2) Bundled with Mono for Mac.What should i do to get a more native look and feel? Please advice

Comment: For the record the first one is the new GTK+ 3 file chooser dialog; the second one is the old GTK+ 2 file chooser dialog.

Comment: @andlabs Thanks.I hope Mono will update the GTK# Version included with the framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either the older open-source MonoMac or the newer Xamarin.Mac to open a [NSOpenPanel](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/constructor/MonoMac.AppKit.NSOpenPanel.NSOpenPanel()/) and use the native OS-X file selector instead of the xplat based GTK 2 version.

Mixing MonoMac dialogs on top of GTK# is possible as long as you remember to initialize the application via the MonoMac static method `NSApplication.Init()`. Do this earlier in the application startup, but after GTK# initializes.

As for opening the native NSOpenPanel, here is an example used within a GTK# Button click handler:

```
button.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
    Application.Invoke (delegate {
        var nsOpenPanel = new NSOpenPanel ();
        nsOpenPanel.ReleasedWhenClosed = true;
        nsOpenPanel.Prompt = "Select file";
        var result = nsOpenPanel.RunModal ();
        if (result == 1) {
            button.Label = nsOpenPanel.Url.ToString ();
        }
    });
};
```

Note: It is always wise to wrap the calls within an `Application.Invoke`delegate so everything is executed on the main GTK UI thread.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.Is this possible for non xamarin.mac(Mono.Mac) applications using the GTK UI?

Comment: You would have to at least use the free/open-source MonoMac version to access the OS-X native dialogs. No need for the licensed Xamarin.Mac in that case... Otherwise you are bound to the stock GTK dialogs, unless you write a complete open file dialog in GTK# yourself.

Comment: Im currently using the free Mono version.

Comment: Is multiple File Selection and Filtering(eg:JPEG Only) possible with NSOpenPanel?

Comment: The `AllowedFileTypes` property accepts a string array so you can set as many filters as your need. http://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/MonoMac.AppKit.NSSavePanel.AllowedFileTypes/

Comment: And the the `AllowsMultipleSelection` is as boolean property to turn on/off multiple selection. There are also properties to allow you to not allow directory selection, etc...

Comment: I tried adding the code.But NSOpenPanel reference is not recognized.Im working in Xamarin Studio using the Mono version 3.1.2.What reference should i add to get this working?Im confused with the different versions of Mono.

Comment: Reference "MonoMac", if you do not have it review the README @ https://github.com/mono/monomac , if you have Xamarin.Mac just reference that .... BTW: Why the 'old' mono version on OS-X?

Comment: I have the newer version 4 will change to it.The current version is 3.BTW According to your answer to my previous question.I just bundled Mono Statically and copied the required files from  Framework/Mono.Framework/lib and made a standalone .app file using platypus.Now it works without mono or gtk installed.But as you have said if i include MonoMac or Xamarin.Mac doesn't i need to bundle that manually.Im just confused with Mono.mac and Monomac isn't Mono.mac same as monomac? I just edited the reference and added monomac.

Comment: okay.Thanks.I understand that xamarin studio only supports gtk2.GTK3 has a better FileChooser.I have GTK3 Folder downloaded.Is there a way to replace it manually(GTK2 with GTK3) ?

Comment: Yes, you will need to include the MonoMac.dll in your app bundle if you are using it, just like any other CIL assembly. If you are statically linking Mono, then I assume you have Xamarin.Mac and would include it.  I assume Mono(dot)Mac and MonoMac are the same, just different people choice(?)

Comment: Thanks a lot,it worked.I downloaded this http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp_Free_Code/Game/Download_NuclearWinter.htm and used the Monomac.dll in it,as i couldn't find a working copy of the dll.Now if i bundle using mkbundle will this ell be included automatically?Or should i copy this locally?

Comment: You can include it when you run mkbundle (mkbundle [options] assembly1 [assembly2...])

Comment: Could you please answer a similar question related to look and feel i posted today http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33461069/gtk-ui-looks-different-when-running-from-bundle-and-when-running-from-xamarin-st